# Choking experienced while using the TCP/IP Adapter for BizTalk Server 2006

Tags: performance, biztalk, tcp, adapter

I am using the TCP/IP Adapter for BizTalk Server 2006 which was obtained from codeplex: http://www.codeplex.com/BTSTCPIP 
Once the application was deployed in production, we started to experience choking in the performance of the application. The more the requests, the more the performance degradation. 
Sometimes, it happens that the receive ports become non-responsive and we have to forcefully restart the host instances to temporarily let the services respond again but we experience the same problems again and again.
I would like to ask if any of you have used the same adapter and have you ever experienced the similar issues? If yes, how can we overcome theses issues.

Thanks.

Comment: are the ports non responsive during or after high volume? do you have suspended messages around the time of failure?

Comment: There are no suspended messages when the problem occurs, the messages just remain enqueued in Active state after the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We experienced similar behaviour but it was a deeper systemic problem.  Is the issue affecting other appplications?  Is your DBA seeing excessive blocking in the database?  Are your SQL Jobs running and/or failing?  Are your backups processing at a regular interval?

I documented the problem we had [Here](http://www.implementsivillage.net/PermaLink,guid,ac3f65fa-0051-48a0-bb8b-f9e741c1a0d1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Are the connection being closed? Are you providing some kind of response if the port is two way? I remember something related to this when I was using the MLLP adapter that comes with the HL7 Pack.